# wordpress custom form and query: return data

Tags: php, wordpress

I have wordpress custom form, and i send data to another page, and there i have such part of code:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all pages
 *
 * This is the template that displays all pages by default.
 * Please note that this is the WordPress construct of pages
 * and that other 'pages' on your WordPress site will use a
 * different template.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Twelve
 * @since Twenty Twelve 1.0
 */
get_header(); 
$args = array(  
        'post_type' => 'part',
        //'paged' => get_query_var('paged'),
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(  
                'taxonomy' => 'brands',
                'field' => 'id',
                'terms' => array($_GET['brands'])  
            ),
            array(  
                'taxonomy' => 'groups',
                'field' => 'id',  
                'terms' => array($_GET['groups'])  
            )  
        ),
        'meta_query' => array(  
            array(  
                'key' => 'price',  
                'value' => array( (int)$_GET['min-price'], (int)$_GET['max-price'] ),
                'type' => 'numeric',
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN' 
            ),
            array(  
                'key' => 'weight',  
                'value' => array( (int)$_GET['min-weight'], (int)$_GET['max-weight'] ),
                'type' => 'numeric',
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN' 
            )
        )
    );
    query_posts($args);
?>

    <div id="primary" class="site-content">
        <div id="content" role="main">

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>
                <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>
            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

but this query didn't view anything, but should! )) Why i didn't get any data, where i'm wrong in my code?

Comment: @Naruto didn't understand you

Comment: Nvm, I didn't read the wordpress, can't help you with that.. sorry

Comment: with only post type condition - it display all post type data

Comment: Mmmh your `query_posts()` seems fine to me. Are you sure that you have actual data in your DB or that both `'tax_query'` and `'meta_query'` should be using [`'relation' => 'AND'`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters)? (`'AND'` is the default value for `'relation'` if this parameter is omitted)

Comment: @mathielo didn't know. how could i check it? data i have sure...

Comment: @mathielo please show code how to do for 'or'

Comment: `$meta_query_args = array(
 'relation' => 'OR', `  did you mean this ?   but when i have empty price but have brand - i must search via brand not price, if i have price and brand - search via it both

Comment: @brabertaser1992 the `'relation'` will only work within _meta_ or _tax_ scopes. Querying `$args` applying `'relation' => 'OR'` you'll have a search like this: `(brands = ? OR groups = ?) AND (price BETWEEN ? AND ? OR weight BETWEEN ? AND ?)`. If you need to search for _tax_ **OR** _meta_, then you should test your conditions before building `$args` array or build your own query to execute.

Comment: @mathielo it is such thing: when price i enter, and weight not - then it search via weight too, but with 0 value